How can I make Laravel Reverb websockets work with Apache
I have a website written with Laravel and Reverb for websockets. Everything works except websockets. They are sent from the browser to the server in the form wss://mydomain.com/app (which throws an error). Server listens on 0.0.0.0:8080. From Reverb's documentation it says that for nginx the following works:
server {
    ...
 
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
 
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    }
 
    ...
}

... but there is no documentation for Apache and my server is on Apache. So how can I redirect an incoming requests wss://mydomain.com/app to local address 0.0.0.0:8080 ?
